# Selecting a random tuple from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Say I have this:

```
d={'a':[(1,2),(3,4)],'b':[(9,2),(5,4)],'c':[(2,2),(7,7)]}
```

where d is a dictionary in python. I'd like to get random tuples out of this corresponding to a particular key using the `random.choice()` method.

This is what I'm doing and it's not working:

```
random.choice(d['a'].values())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d['a']` is already a list, so you don't need to call `.values()` on it.

```
import random
d = {
    'a': [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
    'b': [(9, 2), (5, 4)],
    'c': [(2, 2), (7, 7)],
}
print(random.choice(d['a']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a random tuple out of key you pick, you've written too much:

```
random.choice(d['a'])
```

(Also NB: You'll need quotes around the keys in the dictionary. Right now you're using, e.g., the undefined variable `a` instead of the string `'a'`.)